# select top record with sharing column's value SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got that table :

```
id    table_id      ....
1         1
2         1
3         1
4         2
5         2
```

I want a query to get top record from all who have the same table_id

Result :

```
id    table_id      ....
1         1
4         2
```

I tried :

```
SELECT        
   id, shift_id, name_of_shift, person_in_shift, 
   starttime_in_shift, endtime_in_shift, table_id, 
   startdate, enddate, point_id
FROM            
   sarcshifttable
WHERE        
   (table_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT table_id
                 FROM sarcshifttable AS sarcshifttable_1))
```

but its bring me all the data and I want just the top one

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Table
  WHERE ID IN
    (SELECT ID FROM ( SELECT MIN(ID)as ID,table_id FROM Table GROUP BY table_id)x)
```

Comment: but i want to get all other information not just table_id

Answer (score 1):

He said he wanted all the columns back, so it will have to be this:

```
SELECT        
   id, shift_id, name_of_shift, person_in_shift, 
   starttime_in_shift, endtime_in_shift, table_id, 
   startdate, enddate, point_id
FROM            
   sarcshifttable
WHERE id IN 
(
 SELECT MIN(id)
 FROM sarcshifttable
 GROUP BY table_id
)
```

Comment: Nice answer - I ended up with the same thing in the end, you understood the requirements a lot faster than I did. :D +1

Answer (score 0):

They're right - by selecting the lowest (`MIN()`) ID grouping by table_id, you can find out the earliest row for that particular table ID.

Something like this:

```
SELECT
  MIN(id), table_id
FROM
  table1
GROUP BY
  table_id
```

**Update:**
Better understanding the request, the following SQL will work:

```
SELECT
  id, shift_id, name_of_shift, person_in_shift, 
   starttime_in_shift, endtime_in_shift, table_id, 
   startdate, enddate, point_id
FROM
  table1
WHERE
  id IN (
    SELECT MIN(ID)
    FROM table1 GROUP BY table_id
  )
```

A [working example (updated) can be seen here at SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/51b31/2).

Comment: I understand now. I've updated my answer as well as the SQLFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @What TABLE
(
    id INT,
    tableId INT
)

INSERT INTO @What
VALUES
(1, 1),
(2, 1),
(3, 1),
(4, 2),
(5, 2)

SELECT a.id, a.tableId
FROM
(   
    SELECT id, tableId, Rank() OVER (PARTITION BY tableId ORDER BY id) localRank
    FROM @What
) a
WHERE a.localRank = 1
ORDER BY  a.id
```

id  tableId

1   1

4   2